# Orchard custom forms with unobtrusive client-side validation

Tags: forms, validation, orchardcms, field

I'm using Orchard's 'Custom Forms' module to build a form by adding a bunch of fields to a content type called 'Booking Form'. It works just fine - I can submit the form and view submissions in the admin pages.

I want to use client-side validation on the fields. I've succeeded in getting jQuery unobtrusive validation to work on my own manually-built forms (using @Html.EditorFor() a property on a viewmodel, and decorating the field [Required]). However, I can't get it to work in this context.

I am guessing this is because the property that's being used to render the input is not decorated with DataAnnotations attributes:

```
namespace Orchard.Core.Common.ViewModels {
    public class TextFieldDriverViewModel {
        public TextField Field { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public TextFieldSettings Settings { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

I think the 'Text' field would need something like [Required] before it for unobtrusive validation to work properly.

Is there any way to achieve unobtrusive validation for fields like this? Obviously decorating the property is undesirable, as then even fields NOT marked as required in the CMS would become required.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha)?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks. The validation that appears in those screenshots is HTML5 validation, provided by the browsers. This has since been disabled with the "novalidate" attribute being applied to forms by default in Orchard 1.6.

Comment: You sure? I recently deployed a website with Orchard 1.6, the contact form in my site used Custom forms and it's validation is working perfectly fine in all browsers.

Comment: Client-side or server-side? Did you need to enable it anywhere and include the javascript files for unobtrusive validation?

Comment: client side, not that i recall.